Generating xaml resources through MSBuild
I have a WPF application and am trying to create a very simple MSBuild step to generate some xaml resources based on an already existing xaml file.
In my App.xaml, I have :
 <Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
             <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme.xaml" />

             <!-- This xaml file is generated via a MSBuild step -->
             <ResourceDictionary Source="OtherResources.xaml" />
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     </ResourceDictionary>
 </Application.Resources>

The Theme.xaml file always exists in the project, but OtherResources.xaml is generated during compilation. It's basically just a power shell script that takes in Themes.xaml, and generates some new colours based on the values in Themes.xaml and gives them a new key. (I've simplified my use case for for this question)
Write-Host 'Creating other resources ...'

$other = Get-Content "Theme.xaml"

$other = $other.Replace("Red", "Red2");
$other = $other.Replace("#FF0000", "#880000");

$other = $other.Replace("Green", "Green2");
$other = $other.Replace("#00FF00", "#008800");

$other = $other.Replace("Blue", "Blue2");
$other = $other.Replace("#0000FF", "#000088");

Set-Content -Path "OtherResources.xaml" -Value $other

To make this work, I have the CreateOtherResources.ps1 script, and then the following in my csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="CreateOtherResources" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild;BeforeRebuild">
        <Delete Files="OtherResources.xaml" />

        <Exec Command="powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File $(ProjectDir)CreateOtherResources.ps1 '$(ProjectDir)'" />
    </Target>

</Project>

The problem I am having is that when OtherResources.xaml doesn't exist on disk (example freshly checkout out from source control), I have to build the solution twice before the OtherResources.xaml content is included in the executable.
Not sure what is happening. The file is definitely generated on the first build, as I can see it on disk. But it's not included, and I get an exception from "App.xaml" about it not being able to find OtherResources.xaml
So it looks like either its building before the target is complete perhaps?
How can I resolve this issue?
One approach that kind of works, is to have a dummy empty OtherResources.xaml, which seems to let the build know that more content is coming. But I would rather avoid this as I don't want files that will end up being generated, also stored in source control.

SDK style projects default include most files that are in the project folder including .xaml files. This is done early before your BeforeBuild target. When the file doesn’t already exist, it’s not included. In your target add an ItemGroup to Include your XAML file to None with KeepDuplicates=false.
